# c++ How to solve : Initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am writing a program that determines the prime factors of a range of numbers. In the program, the `startingNumber` and `endingNumber` of the range is indicated as a `std::pair`.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const long long MAX = 100000000; // One hundred million
long long factor[MAX];


pair<const long long, const long long> get_pair() // Gets user start and end number to establish range in vector.
{
    long long largestNumber = 100000000;
    long long smallestNumber = 2;
    std::pair<long long, long long> p;
    cout << "Enter a start number: ";
    cin >> p.first;
    while (p.first < smallestNumber || p.first > largestNumber || cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cout << "That's not a valid choice. Please try again (" << smallestNumber << " - " << largestNumber << "): ";
        cin >> p.first;
    }
    cout << "Enter a end number: ";
    cin >> p.second;
    while (p.second < p.first || p.second > largestNumber || cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
        cout << "That's not a valid choice. Please try again (" << p.first << " - " << largestNumber << "): ";
        cin >> p.second;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return make_pair(p.first, p.second);
}

vector<long long> rangeToVector(const long long &startingNumber, const long long &endingNumber) // creates vector of numbers from std::pair.
{
    vector<long long> iterator;

    for (long long i = 1; i <= ((10 - 1) + 1); i += 1) iterator.push_back((1-1)+i);

    return iterator;
}
void precalculate() // Calculates all of the prime numbers between 1 and MAX. Stores prime numbers from smallest to largest.
{
    for (long long i = 1; i < MAX; i++) { // stores 1 through Max in factor.
        factor[i] = i;
    }

    for (long long i = 2; i * i < MAX; i++) if (factor[i] == i) { // If factor[i] is even.
        for (long long j = i + i; j < MAX; j += i) {
            factor[j] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works as intended. The code is then input into the follow function, I am unsure as to whether or works correctly(Since my function in main will not compile).

```
vector<long long> get_factors(vector<long long> &vect) // performs calculation on rangeToVector[i] (determined by precalculate) until it is not divisible, then it returns those that were divided into the number as prime factors of the rangeToVector[i].
{
    vector<long long> factors;
    for (auto i : vect)
    {
        while (vect[i] > 1)
        {
            long long f = factor[vect[i]];
            factors.push_back(f);
            vect[i] /=f;
        }
    }

    sort(factors.begin(), factors.end()); // sorts the vector.
    factors.erase(unique(factors.begin(), factors.end()), factors.end()); // erases duplicates (requires sorted vector).

    return factors;
}
```

In main (line 3), I receive the error underlining `rangeToVector`, `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`.

```
int main()
{
    for (auto i : get_factors(rangeToVector(pairs.first, pairs.second))) // get_factors returns factors of numbers in vector rangeToVector
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I attempted to make the values in `rangeToVector` constants, but this has not solved the problem. My question is, is my referencing incorrect? Should I pass the function differently? Or what can I do to the code to allow `get_factors` to take the factors of `rangeToVector[i]` in main on line 3. I am new to c++, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You never declare `pairs`, there are no includes and maybe there are other compiler errors that are not related to your actual question

Comment: A temporary object (returned from `rangeToVector`) cannot be bound to non-`const` reference (`vector<long long> &vect` as an argument of `get_factors`). There must be a duplicate somewhere..

Comment: You're passing a temporary to a non-const reference, so stop doing that. For example: `vector<long long> values; for (auto i : get_factors(values))`

Comment: There are several logic errors in the `get_factors` function (e.g. you use `factor[x]` when `factor` is empty,  and you almost certainly access out of bounds of `vect`)

Comment: @M.M factor is filled by the precalculate() function.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies here:

```
std::vector<long long> get_factors(std::vector<long long> &vect) { ... }
```

The variable `vect` is an lvalue reference, that means it's a reference that cannot bind to temporary variables.

Yet, you use it like that:

```
get_factors(rangeToVector(...))
```

Where `rangeToVector` returns a temporary.

The solution to that is simply to make `vect` a constant lvalue reference, which can bind to a temporary:

```
//                                     const here  -------v
std::vector<long long> get_factors(std::vector<long long> const& vect) { ... }
```

You have many other problems in your code, I suggest you to read a good C++ and try to not assume things about it's syntax. For example, you don't use range for loops correctly:

```
for (auto i : vect) {
    while (vect[i] > 1) {
        long long f = factor[vect[i]];
        factors.push_back(f);
        vect[i] /=f;
    }
}
```

The correct usage will be:

```
 for (auto& i : vect) {
    while (i > 1) {
        long long f = factor[i];
        factors.push_back(f);
        i /= f;
    }
}
```

Comment: The function modifies `vect` so this is not a complete solution

Comment: @Shayne this is because you don't use the for loop properly. Replace `vect[i]` by `i` and it will fix your error.

Comment: Okay, so by correcting the for loop it removes all errors from the code. But, when I insert a start number and an end number the program fails and says. "Debug assertion failed" Line: 1809. Expression: vector subscript out of range. What does this mean? How can I resolve it? The only time it does not fail is if both the start and end number are the same.

Comment: @Shayne you'll have to debug your program. You are accessing elements in a vector past it's current size. There's probably a bug somewhere, where you treat a value as an index where it don't quite make sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thank everyone for their comments and suggestions, it helped me solve my problem. As Guillaume Racicot mentioned, I definitely needed to study up more on vectors. Again, thank you.

My problem was within the code below:

```
vector<long long> get_factors(vector<long long> &vect) // Notice how I have it relying on "vector<long long> &vect".
{
    vector<long long> factors;
    for (auto i : vect)
    {
        while (vect[i] > 1)
        {
            long long f = factor[vect[i]];
            factors.push_back(f);
            vect[i] /=f;
        }
    }

    sort(factors.begin(), factors.end()); // sorts the vector.
    factors.erase(unique(factors.begin(), factors.end()), factors.end()); // erases duplicates (requires sorted vector).

    return factors;
}
```

and the way that I called it in main:

```
 for (auto i : get_factors(rangeToVector(pairs.first, pairs.second))) // get_factors returns factors of numbers in vector rangeToVector
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
```

In order to solve my problem, I needed to realize that in order to access vectors/arrays, you have to create a for loop to gather its values. Therefore, my solution was as follows.

```
vector<long long> get_factors(long long x, vector<long long> vec )
    {
             vector<long long> factors;
        while (x > 1) { /* insert code*/ vec.push_back(f); } // Or use a for loop.

           return vec;
    }

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<long long> temp1;

    for (long long val : inputVector) // where initial data was stored (see original post)
            {
                  result1 = getPrimes(val, temp1); // iterate through vec as long long in function
            }

     return 0;
}
```